# How grouping rows by field in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

[image: see images here]

I have a problem when creating excel files with the phpExcel library.

I want to create groups on certain lines based on the sales column (with same sales name).

I have made the file manually by using the Subtotal feature on the Data tab in Excel.

Is it possible that phpexcel has such feature?

You can see the sample file that I mean on the link / image that I uploaded.

Comment: you want to group them each 50 rows ?

Comment: no, i want grouping the rows by salesman. Like Abdul Karim, he have 23 data, and i grouping them and in the last row, he have the total. how i can implement that in phpexcel? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can group the rows like this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('5')->setOutlineLevel(1);
```

For more details you can visit [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#showhide-a-row).
You can also go [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_outline1.html) and [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_outlines.html#outlines) for working examples

Comment: i have used this command, but i can't implement that code with dynamic way. i want use this command only by salesman (group by salesman)... can u give me some logic for that? :'(

Answer (score 0):

Using the PHPExcel , you can use the methods :

- setOutlineLevel($level)  // the level of the current row
- setVisible(false) // show or hide the group
- setCollapsed(true) // add collapse to group (as figure out in the picture above )

THe point here is to define group condition , example :

> We suppose that the file excel is already generated with PHPExcel and
>   now you are going to read the file again for grouping rows .

First let's read the column C that contain name of salesman and store them inside the **$salemans** :

```
$salesmans = array(); 

/*
the output of $salesmans seems to be something like :
[0] ==> "Abdul Karim",
[1] ==> "Apan Total",
[2] ==> ""Ari Total
*/
```

> The array $salesman should have distinct value , so when trying to
>   insert inside the array verify if the current value doesn't exist
>   already in the $salesmans.

Example :

```
$salesmans=array();
if (!in_array($currentSalesman, $salesmans))
{
   $array[] = $value; 
}
```

Here , we are going to to set the level of each row by getting the value of the current salesman with the key in the $salesmans

> Caution : please try to modify this section because i'm not getting
>   how you manage fetch rows.I'm just making code more clear to understand easy

```
for ($row = 0; $row <= 10000; ++$row) { 
    $currentsalesman = $row['c']; // 
    $keylevel = array_search($currentsalesman, $salesmans);// this will return the key in $salesmans array
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getRowDimension($row)
            ->setOutlineLevel($keylevel) // set here the level .
            ->setVisible(false)
            ->setCollapsed(true);
}
```